# add multiple appointmentsTask in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, appointment

I have successfully added single appointment using this code now i want to add multiple appointment pro grammatically in a single loop.for example i want to add 5 appointment at a time using loop where dates for every appointment is available in a List.
Thanks in advance :)

```
SaveAppointmentTask saveAppointmentTask = new SaveAppointmentTask();          
saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = nearestDate;

saveAppointmentTask.EndTime = nearestDate.AddMinutes(3) ;

saveAppointmentTask.Subject = "Meet Ali"; // appointment subject

saveAppointmentTask.Location = "In Office"; // appointment location

saveAppointmentTask.Details = "Meet Ali to discuss product launch";//appointment details
saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.Reminder.FifteenMinutes;
saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.OutOfOffice;
saveAppointmentTask.Show();
```

Comment: Wait for a sec Ill come up with a work around :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto(v=vs.95).aspx

 Go through this link youll get to understand why this method is called whenever we return to our app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code as Navigated To event is all the time called when you land up in the page

```
private SaveAppointmentTask saveAppointmentTask;
    private List<int> listMinutes = new List<int>();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            listMinutes.Add(i);
        }

    }

    int countAdded = 0;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (countAdded < 10)
        {

            saveAppointmentTask = new SaveAppointmentTask();
            saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(listMinutes[countAdded]);

            saveAppointmentTask.EndTime = saveAppointmentTask.StartTime.Value.AddMinutes(2);

            saveAppointmentTask.Subject = "Meet Ali"; // appointment subject

            saveAppointmentTask.Location = "In Office"; // appointment location

            saveAppointmentTask.Details = "Meet Ali to discuss product launch";//appointment details
            saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
            saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.Reminder.FifteenMinutes;
            saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.OutOfOffice;
            countAdded++;
            saveAppointmentTask.Show();
        }
        else { 
            // do not add anything
        }


    }
```

save i that is the count in some application state or a tokes so that you can know if you have added the events :) `Appplication.Current.Resources.Add("token", "number added")`

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what u want to say??
what is the difference here?
still issue not resolved . I have to call this function inside loop so what is the difference here ????

Comment: No No see the thing here is when you call saveAppointmentTask.Show() ----- Suppose you have your lists first appointment----; then it shows another screen where you save your appointment. Now you cannot loop when that save screen is there. But when you have saved the appointment clicking save then you again landup in this event on NavigatedTo() .. Here you again add list's 2nd element and agan do saveAppointmentTask.Show();. Then again save it you will come up here . Add list 3rd appoint ment andt do saveAppointmentTask.Show();.

Comment: Same way just save the no of appointment added once filled with appoint ments you can go ahead do the rest of the task :) Pleas let me know if the above explanation is not clear.

Comment: The problem with windows phoen is once you go to another page you loose the apps page. But on saving when you come back then this event is fired. Y the hell some one down voted?? please provide a reason.

Comment: i don't know who down voted you :( and let me try this code and get back to you :)

Comment: tell me if you cannot implement. ill give a list demo then and update the answer :)

Comment: sorry but why u wrote this line i am new to windows phone and c# so dont know much about this :
Appplication.Current.Resources.Add("token", "number added")

Comment: I have updated the code. for application resources ill demonstarte later. Have some work . be back in an hour

Comment: actually i am working in phonegap and i have written plugin for calender to push dates to calender which are selected by user. Any idea how ur provided solution can be used there?

Comment: Now that goes out of my scope :( You can have a separate question for Phonegap developers linking this one or my Logic. But I don't actually know how phonegap handles these and I don't  want to do I blind Guess or some links :)

Comment: i got your solution working in my phonegap App thanks for the directions. without your directions i wouldnt have been able to sole it. Thanks again anobik

Comment: My Pleasure I helped. U can always ask if any concern :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically save all appointments. You would have to launch the task in each iteration, and user interaction would be nedded in each.

A possible option is to use the `Live Connect API`. That would allow you to programatically create apointments in user's Live calendar:

[Interacting with calendars (Live Connect API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523)

This way you don't interact with the phone calendar, but the users's Live calendar, which can be synchronized in the phone. Of course, the user will need to authenticate.